# cast a type from anonymous to something else in a query -- needing to keep scope for a try/catch block

Tags: c#, linq

EDIT --  I would really like some feedback as to why this question was downvoted?
I gave both a working and non-working version of code, showed everything I tried and responded quickly to suggestions.
Perhaps some of you have forgotten how slow of a climb it is in the beginning when every point of rep. counts!

I am open to improving the question title.
In C#6

The below code works:

```
DistributionStopInformation stop = new DistributionStopInformation();

stop = (from s in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
                        where s.UniqueIdNo == item.UniqueIdNo
                        select s).First();
```

but as soon as I don't want everything returned I get the error :
`Cannot implicitly convert type <anonymous....`

Like so:

```
DistributionStopInformation stop = new DistributionStopInformation();

stop = (from s in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
                          where s.UniqueIdNo == item.UniqueIdNo
                          select new
                          {
                              createdby = s.CreatedBy
                          }).First();
```

I have tried creating a new class and inheriting from base class like:

```
class stopInfo : DistributionStopInformation
{

}
stopInfo stop = new stopInfo();

stop = (from s in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
                          where s.UniqueIdNo == item.UniqueIdNo
                          select new
                          {
                              createdby = s.CreatedBy
                          }).First();
```

But I get the same error.

Tried several different things before turning here for help...

EDIT:
The reason I am needing to do this (delcare it first) is that I need to wrap it in a try/catch block like so -- obviously the newItem line will be trying to access the stop variable out of scope.

```
   try
   {
       var stop = (from s in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
                   where s.UniqueIdNo == item.UniqueIdNo
                   select new
                   {
                       createdby = s.CreatedBy
                   }).First();
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
       throw;
   }

   newItem.CreatedBy = stop.CreatedBy
```

EDIT:
OK, by request here is the complete code -- in the below stop is out of scope below:

```
       foreach (var item in newItems)
        {

            //go see if this item exists already
            var itemCheck = (from i in aDb.recent_items where i.item_number == item.ItemNumber select i).ToArray();

            if (itemCheck.Count() == 0)
            {

                //go get the stop

                try
                {
                    stopInfo stop = new stopInfo();

                    var stop = (from s in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
                                where s.UniqueIdNo == item.UniqueIdNo
                                select new
                                {
                                    s.BranchId,
                                    s.RouteCode,
                                    s.StopName,
                                    s.StopAddress,
                                    s.StopCity,
                                    s.StopState,
                                    s.StopZipPostalCode,
                                }).First();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
                    //update the counter which will be returned            
               itemCountUpdated++;
                //give em some info so we know its still working...
                Console.WriteLine("Doing number: " + itemCountUpdated);
                //create a new item
                recent_items newItem = new recent_items();

                //grab the info for each property
                newItem.azure_record_created = DateTime.Now;
                newItem.branch_id = stop.BranchId;
                newItem.datatrac_record_created = item.DatetimeCreated;
                if (stop.RouteCode.Length >= 3) { newItem.branch_id_from_route_code = stop.RouteCode.ToString().Substring(0, 3); }
                newItem.datatrac_unique_id_no = item.UniqueIdNo;
                newItem.item_description = item.ItemDescription;
                newItem.item_number = item.ItemNumber;
                newItem.item_sequence = item.ItemSequenceNo;
                newItem.item_weight = item.ExpectedWeight;
                newItem.route_code = stop.RouteCode;
                newItem.stop_address = stop.StopAddress;
                newItem.stop_city = stop.StopCity;
                newItem.stop_name = stop.StopName;
                newItem.stop_state = stop.StopState;
                newItem.stop_zipcode = stop.StopZipPostalCode;

                //add the record to the context
                aDb.recent_items.Add(newItem);

                //if this is the 100th time then write the records

            if (itemCountUpdated % 100 == 0)
                {
                    aDb.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

        }
        //write out any records that are still left
        aDb.SaveChanges();
```

Per suggestion tried this with the same error:

```
 var stop = new { branchID = "tst" };

                try
                {
                    //stopInfo stop = new stopInfo();

                    stop = (from s in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
                                where s.UniqueIdNo == item.UniqueIdNo
                                select new
                                {
                                    s.BranchId,

                                }).First();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
```

Per another suggestion I have tried this as well:

```
  try
                {
                    //stopInfo stop = new stopInfo();

                   DistributionStopInformation stop = (from s in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
                                where s.UniqueIdNo == item.UniqueIdNo
                                select new DistributionStopInformation
                                {
                                    s.BranchId,

                                }).First();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
```

but I get a:

Cannot initialize type 'stopInfoClass' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: what about `select new DistributionStopInformation{ CreatedBy = s.CreatedBy }`?

Comment: Why does `newItem.CreatedBy = stop.CreatedBy;` have to be outside the `try catch` block?

Comment: Good question...I could expand the try catch block but it would span about a hundred lines as I am doing a LOT with stop after that.  Would wind up with nested try/catches .... I just normally try and avoid that for cleaner reading.

Comment: You shouldn't need nested try catches within one method.  Just catch the exceptions in order of how specific they are.

Comment: No reason for the internal try catch.  Wrap the whole code in the try catch.

Comment: Why do you even *have* try/catch at all, if all you´re doing in the catch is throw the exception further?

Comment: I will be doing something in the catch -- I will need to created a different record showing what was not there.

Comment: Why not `var stop = ... select new stopInfo { ... }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific problem, you could just remove the try catch altogether (it doesn't achieve anything). And just do:

```
var stop = (from s in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
            where s.UniqueIdNo == item.UniqueIdNo
            select new
            {
                s.BranchId,
                s.RouteCode,
                s.StopName,
                s.StopAddress,
                s.StopCity,
                s.StopState,
                s.StopZipPostalCode,
            }).First();
//update the counter which will be returned            
itemCountUpdated++;
// etc
```

**Background before the entire method was shared is below...**

One possible approach would be to use the anonymous type as you already are, and then new up your `DistributionStopInformation` after the fact. Something like:

```
var anonStop = (from s in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
    where s.UniqueIdNo == item.UniqueIdNo
    select new { CreatedBy = s.CreatedBy }).First();

var stop = new DistributionStopInformation { CreatedBy = anonStop.CreatedBy };
```

Alternatively, avoid the anonymous type altogether:

```
var stop = (from s in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
    where s.UniqueIdNo == item.UniqueIdNo
    select new DistributionStopInformation { CreatedBy = s.CreatedBy }).First();
```

If you want to use the anonymous type (and not use `DistributionStopInformation`  at all) then you need to declare an anonymous variable **outside** of your try catch. Something like:

```
var stop = new { createdby = "a"};

try
{
    stop = (from s in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
                  where s.UniqueIdNo == item.UniqueIdNo
                  select new
                  {
                      createdby = s.CreatedBy

                  }).First();        
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Picky point, but you don't need the `()`, for example: `new DistributionStopInformation { property1...`

Comment: I feel it looks a little tidier, but it's personal preference really.

Comment: But the program crashes whenever the query does not return anything, such as when the UniqueIdNo does not exist....that is why I was doing a try/catch in the first place.  Is there a better way of checking for that?

Comment: Thanks for the catch....yes, changing the case addresses it.  Is there a way to tell it its type besides putting blank data in for each field?  Something better than:   BranchId ="", RouteCode = "",

Comment: No there isn't @JoeRuder . You will need to put "" for strings, 0 for ints etc.

Comment: @mjwills -- thank you for the help, I wound up going with this solution as the other compiled but had a runtime error.

Answer (score 3):

Try this if you must keep the anon type with only the one property, although you won't be able to pass the `stop` variable to other methods as it's an anon type

```
var stop = (from s in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
            where s.UniqueIdNo == item.UniqueIdNo
            select new
            {
                createdby = s.CreatedBy
            }).First();
```

Comment: No, he tried to select a new anon type in a known type

Comment: @HimBromBeere - That's not what OP did since they are declaring the type of `stop` as `DistributionStopInformation`.

Comment: Adding var does not fix it....if you leave the definition above it then you get the error that the variable stop is already defined in scope (obviously) and if I just remove the definition then it does work, but it causes another problem which is why I am needing to define it in the first place.  I will up date the question with more info...just a sec...

Comment: I was assuming you would delete the declaration above, that's why I left it out of my answer.

Comment: How do I cast the `stop` to `DistributionStopInformation`?

Comment: yes..I am needing to wrap it in a try/catch block, and there are a lot more than just one property -- I am only listing the one for brevity.

Comment: @mjwills You don't, I'm assuming the OP just wanted an object with this one property that's why they were selecting an anon type.

Comment: I think the point is that OP doesn't know how to *not* project to an anonymous type and would much prefer the concrete type provided.

Comment: @DavidG They provided the code to not project it to an anonymous type right in the question, so we know that's not the case.

Comment: @Servy Yes, but presumably because they don't know any better

Answer (score 0):

When writing `Select new { ...  }` you´re creating an instance of an anonymous type. As the name suggests that types has no name and thus you can´t do much with it, in particular you can´t return it from a method and handle it within the calling code appropriately. Also you can´t cast it neither implictely nor excplicitely to your desired type.

However you seem to have a clear idea on what your query actually returns, basically instances that have a bunch of properties. In addition you already seem to have a class that holds those information: `stopInfo` (be aware that the naming-convention suggests to use `StopInfo` instead).

So you should just use this:

```
try
{
    stopInfo stop = (from s in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
                    where s.UniqueIdNo == item.UniqueIdNo
                    select new stopInfo // here you instantiate your class
                    {
                        BranchId = s.BranchId,
                        RouteCode = s.RouteCode,
                        StopName = s.StopName,
                        StopAddress = s.StopAddress,
                        StopCity = s.StopCity,
                        StopState = s.StopState,
                        StopZipPostalCode = s.StopZipPostalCode,
                    }).First();
    }
catch (Exception)
{
    // exception-handling, e.g. logging
    throw;
}
```

Now you can even declare your variable *outside* your try/catch and set it *inside*:

```
stopInfo stop;
try { stop = ... }
catch { ... }
```

Comment: I get the following and I am not sure how to address this (sorry!)  Cannot initialize type 'stopInfoClass' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: What again is `stopInfoClass` and how does it relate to `stopInfo`?

Comment: It is just a empty class inheriting from DstributionStopinformations:   class stopInfoClass : DistributionStopInformation
    {
       
    }   In the example above it was originally called stopInfo vs stopInfoClass  - the only reason it exists is I was trying to solve the problem that way...

Comment: You have to use the tagre class-names property-names as well as in my edit.: e.g `select new StopInfo { BranchId = s.BranchId ... }`

Comment: What is the benefit of using `stopInfo` vs `DistributionStopInformation`?

Comment: If the former doesn´t have any properties I doubt there´s any advantage. You can probably omit the class completely. You *may* use it to indicate that an instance is a database-instance, while the other one is just a wrapper holding the values (a simple DTO).

Comment: For whatever reason this compiled fine, but as soon as it hit the code running it produced this error:  "Explicit construction of entity type 'CopsReportingContext.DistributionStopInformation' in query is not allowed."

Comment: Sure, you can´t create database-instances this way. You may however create a DTO-class with the same properties as your entities and instantaiet that instead. However this won´t work for your `stopInfo`-class I suppose, as it derives from your entities-class.